# Getting an injector unpr error, when creating a firebase login system?

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a firebase login system. For the moment I am trying to assign the registration system to the firebase database system. For some reason I am getting this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/unpr?p0=%24firebaseProvider%20%3C-%20%24firebase%20%3C-%20regCtrl
```

I've checked the error documentation and it talks about the dependency and spelling being correct. The error seems to be happening when I go on to the registration page:

Here is the app.js:

```
var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('logCtrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {

  $scope.trylogin=function trylogin() {
      var username= $scope.login;
        var pass = $scope.password;
        if (pass.length<6|| pass.length===""){
            alert('Password too short');
            return false;
        }
        if(username.length<4|| username.length ===""){
            alert('Username is too short');
            return false;
        }
        else{
            location.replace('http://localhost:63342/firebaseLogin/test.html');
        }
    }


}]);

app.controller('regCtrl',['$scope', '$firebase', '$firebaseAuth', function ($scope, $firebase, $firebaseAuth) {
    var ref= firebase.database().ref();
    var auth=$firebaseAuth();


    $scope.register=function () {

        auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            $scope.userregister,
            $scope.passregister
        ).then(function (reguser) {
                $scope.message="Thanks for registering " + $scope.userregister;

        }).catch(function (error) {
            $scope.message="invalid";
        });
        console.log('it works');


    }

}])
```

here is the register.html:

```
<html  lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <h1>Registration page</h1>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script>
        var config={
            apiKey: "AIzaSyAD5cGUvMlkj-qTgfRmZfyB86b0q_6pFvc",
            authDomain: "core-waters-237812.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://core-waters-237812.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "core-waters-237812",
            storageBucket: "core-waters-237812.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "474778505291",
            appId: "1:474778505291:web:1d7b0baa064a325854fdce"
        }
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="regCtrl">

<form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="register()">
<label for="reguser"> Username</label>
<input ng-model="userregister" id="reguser" type="text">
<br>
<label for="regpass">Password</label>
<input ng-model="passregister" id="regpass" type="text">
<br>

<button type="button" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Register</button>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the AngularJS bindings for Firebase from here [AngularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire) and then add it as dependency.

In your example you are injecting `$firebase` service in your `regCtrl` controller but you never declared its module as a `myApp` dependency.

```
var app= angular.module('myApp',['firebase']);
```